# How to select a model when AIC values are close?

Tags: aic

We are trying out different link functions with glm models and AIC values are very close with about ~1 point difference. Let's say we are using Gaussian glm with log,inverse and identity link functions. Since the AIC values are very close(I have to add that the complexity of all models are the same, all contain the same independent variables and such) does this mean it does not matter which one we choose or should we run some other tests to see which link functions suits better?

Edit: I also used BIC later and the values are again close about ~1.5 points difference between highest and lowest BIC values.The lowest AIC model is again lowest BIC model.

Comment: What is "very close"?

Comment: @StephanKolassa edited the question

Comment: If the complexity of all the models are the same, I would choose the one with the lowest AIC. However, I would suggest that you also try BIC to see whether it yields the same results.

Comment: @Stochastic edited question about BIC. Also see from BIC formulation that the only difference from AIC is the penalty term is log of observations. The number of observations are the same for all 3 models so I would expect the ordering as the AIC ,right?

Comment: Yes you are correct indeed, makes sense that the BIC gives the same results then, so I would suggest you go with that model, since it has the lowest AIC and BIC